# Why Post method not encrypt there header in Tomcat7 on HTTPS/SSL

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, web, https

when I generate key by Openssl or keytool and config server.xml like this:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="SSL"
           keystoreFile="D://work//cert//server.p12"
           keystorePass="123456"
           keystoreType="PKCS12"
           truststoreFile="D://work//cert//ca.p12"
           truststorePass="123456"
           truststoreType="PKCS12"/>
```

or like this:

```
<Connector port="8443" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
            SSLEnabled="true" keystoreFile="D://work//cert//test.keystore"
            keystorePass="123456" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

then I restart Tomcat,and success to access https://localhost:8443.
so easy,I think I'm super hero.
But!!!
When I use HTTPFOX in Firefox,I can see those Headers and POST Data,But via Https,It will be encrypt ,
so I'm confused.

Comment: Correct me if I am incorrect, but HTTPFox operates within the browser, no? It should therefore reasonably only be able to access the decrypted data. So I don't think you can reliably verify HTTPS functionality by this means.

Comment: But when you log in Stackoverflow,you can not see the headers and post data with HTTPFOX

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if HTTPFOX will get the decrypted HTTP traffic from Firefox, but it sounds on you like it doesn't.
If you are using a proxy to connect to the server you might get cleartext HTTP headers before the connection is setup between the client and the final https server.
To be sure, I would use Wireshark and see what is actually being sent over the network...